# Double Returns Zero C

Tags: c, double

When I print out a specific double, it returns a zero.  I print the value in the function and it prints the correct value.  However if I print it in my main, it gives me a zero.

Main:

```
 double med = median(array, counter);
 printf("The median is %.0lf\n", med);
```

Function:

```
 double median(double array[], int length) {
      double med = 0;
      if(length % 2 != 0) {
           med = array[(length-1)/2];
      }
      else {
           double medTot = array[length/2] + array[(length/2)-1];
           printf("%.0f\n", medTot);
           med = (medTot/2);
           printf("%.0f\n", med);
      }
      return med;
 }
```

Could someone help lead me in the right direction towards what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to change your format specifiers in your printf statements in the function from `%f` to `%lf` for `double`, in main you are doing it right

Comment: It prints in my function but not in my main, however.

Comment: Please show us the the full code and also show what input do you have, what output do you get and what output do you expect.

Comment: Try compiling the code with all warnings on. In `gcc` and derivatives, use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @Rizier123  "have to change your format specifiers in your printf statements in the function from `%f` to `%lf` for `double`" is not so.  `"%f"` and `"%lf"` work equally well for `double`.  C11dr §7.21.6.1 7 "... `l` ...has no effect on a following `a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G` conversion
specifier."

Comment: @chux Is this the same for C89, C99 and C90 ?

Comment: @Rizier123  Unsure about earlier version, but suspect `l` was in C99 and before that using `l` was UB.  Just checked, `l` is in C99.

Comment: @chux Okay thanks didn't knew that one :D

Comment: @Rizier123  In C89, using `l` with is OK with `d , i , o , u , x , or X`, else it is UB.  http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.9.6.1

Comment: @Rizier123: It is the `scanf()` family of functions that requires `"%lf"` for `double`.  The asymmetry arises because you cannot pass a `float` to a variadic function like `printf()` because of the automatic promotion to `double` in the variadic portion of the argument list.

Answer (score 4):

You probably need a prototype for `median` that `main` can see.

Comment: My prototype is in a .h file

Comment: Just out of curiosity from which part of the code can you tell/guess that he needs a prototype for his function? (Want to learn something here :D)

Comment: @Rizier123, because in the absence of prototypes, return types default to `int`.

Comment: OKAY, @lhf is right, once I put a prototype in my main, it worked.  However, my .h file should be working.

Comment: @lhf Thanks, didn't know that one before!

Comment: @Rizier123 further info; that is a rule from C89. In C99 and later, missing prototypes mean the compiler has to give an error.  (However many compilers will give a warning and then compile anyway using the C89 rule; the poster may either have ignored warnings, or been in C89 mode)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a declaration for `median()` in scope, the compiler will assume it returns an `int`, and when it converts the 'assumed `int`' into a `double`, things go haywire (or to zero).  C99 and C11 require the function to be declared before it is used, though.

So, you need:

```
extern double median(double array[], int length);  // Prototype
extern double median();                            // Declaration
```

or equivalent in scope before you call `median()`.  Note that the second declaration is not a prototype; it simply declares a function with an indeterminate (but not variadic) argument list that returns a `double`.

I see from a comment that you have declared the function in a header.  You've not shown the header content (or the relevant sub-section of the header), nor have you shown or stated that the header is included before the function is used.  You should also include the header before the function is defined, so that the header cross-checks the definition with the use of the function.  And you need the full prototype, not just the function declaration, to get the full benefit from the cross-checking.

Comment: `extern` is redundant here. (Mentioning this incase OP thinks it is important because you included it)

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I prefer to use `extern` for explicitness. The declaration should be in a header. Variables declared in a header should be prefixed with `extern`, and so, for symmetry, the function declarations in a header should also be prefixed with `extern`.  If you choose to omit it, so be it (that's covered under the 'or equivalent' comment) — but it is not wrong to use `extern` before a function declaration (when it isn't a `static` function) and it is the way I write the declarations.